# Given an unsorted array  of n integers and an integer x, rearrange the elements in 

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, pseudocode

Given an unsorted array  of n integers and an integer x, rearrange the elements in  such that all elements less than or equal to x come before any elements larger than x.

**Note :** Don't have to include integer x in the new array.

What is the running time complexity of your algorithm? Explain your answer.

Comment: Hi Can you share what code you have tried so far?

Comment: @J.S There is standard algorithm std::partition in the C++ Standard.:)

Comment: Given a problem, can you make an attempt? Explain your attempt.

Comment: @J.S See questions about the quick sort in this site.:)

Comment: There is a simple O(n) in place algorithm. Forget classical sort algorithms

Answer (score -1):

To attempt this, you first need to understand sorting algorithms, Big O notation, then see which sorting algorithm best fits the question asked.

1) Given your problems defines that some values come before a set point, and some after, a merge sort would be best here. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

2) Have a read about Big O notation, and time complexity of certain sorting algorithms. There is always a best case and worst case. You can also calculate the complexity of any algorithm you design using this notation. See below.

[Calculating complexity of an algorithm](https://medium.com/@StueyGK/algorithm-time-complexity-and-big-o-notation-51502e612b4d)

EDIT:
To help, here is a solution.

**Part 1:**

```
function sortHalf(List listToSort, value x):
    List firstHalf;
    List secondHalf;
    for (Integer i in listToSort):
        if i less than x then firstHalf.add(i);
        else if i greater than x then secondHalf.add(i);
    loop
    List finalList;
    finalList.addAll(firstHalf);
    finalList.addAll(secondHalf);
    return finalList;
end
```

**Part 2:**

The above algorithm would have a time complexity of `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the `listToSort`. Best case would be `O(1)`, where there is 1 element, and worst case is `O(n)`

Comment: `[you] need to understand sorting algorithms [for this]` no, neither the elements smaller than *x* nor those greater need to be in any specific order. This invalidates any claims regarding sorting.

Comment: The question clearly defines that the list needs to end up sorted such that smaller values than x are before it in the list, and larger values are after. This in itself is sorted based on the value of x. You are correct in stating the values do not need to be in any order as long as it fits the rule. But this still fits the definition of a `sorted` list - `Sorted - organized, arranged, or dealt with satisfactorily.` @greybeard